# Import symbol set from another project or folder

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

I'd like to import another project's 'symbol library' and have it appear in the dropdown (image attached) 'Insert > Symbols'.
Importing it in this way also makes it appear in the right hand 'prototyping' window (2nd image attached).

I have a project that links to another projects symbol library, I just don't know how they did it. I'd like to recreate this!

[image: Insert > Symbols]
[image: prototyping window]

Answer (score 2):

You want to add the file where your symbols are as a library.

To do that, you open your preferences panel, go to the "libraries" tab, and click the "Add library" button. Browse to the source of your symbol and add. Those symbols should now be accesible from any sketch file.

[image]